# Excluding a Grails build scope dependency

Tags: grails, build, dependencies

Using Grails 2.4.3, how can I exclude a dependency that's defined in the `build` scope?

#### Example

Grails is bundled with the library `spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar`; when adding the standard global dependency exclusion:

```
...
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits('global') {
        excludes 'spock-core'
    }
...
```

Spock is excluded from all dependency scopes except for the `build` scope.

Answer (score 0):

Is the issue that you don't want it in your .war file? If so you can remove it like so:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
  delete(file:"${stagingDir}/WEB-INF/lib/spock-core-0.7-groovy-2.0.jar")
}
```

Comment: No, not just in the war; across all scopes